# Creating a dictionary with multiple values per key from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
listofdics = [{'StrId': 11, 'ProjId': 1},{'StrId': 11,'ProjId': 2},
              {'StrId': 22, 'ProjId': 3},{'StrId': 22, 'ProjId': 4},
              {'StrId': 33, 'ProjId': 5},{'StrId': 33, 'ProjId': 6},
              {'StrId': 34, 'ProjId': 7}]
```

I need to get all `ProjId` values for `StrId` that are duplicate. So this is the output I'm looking for:

```
new_listofdics = [{11:[1,2]}, {22:[3,4]}, {33:[5,6]], {34:[7]}]
```

I wrote a function that creates a list of dictionaries with `StrId` values as keys, and a list with all `ProjId` that share the same key as values. Here it is:

```
def compare_projids(listofdics):
    proj_ids_dups = {} 

    for row in listofdics:       
        id_value = row['StrId']
        proj_id_value = row['ProjId']
        proj_ids_dups[id_value]=proj_id_value

        if row['StrId'] == id_value:
            sum_ids = []
            sum_ids.append(proj_id_value)  
        proj_ids_dups[id_value]=sum_ids
     return proj_ids_dups
```

This is the output I get now:

```
new_listofdics=  {33: [6], 34: [7], 11: [2], 22: [4]}
```

What I see is that`append` replaces each `ProjId` value with the last one iterated, instead of adding them at the end of the list.

How can I fix this?...

Comment: Its not the `append`. You are creating a new list object every time with `sum_ids = []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear why you need to have such output `new_listofdics = [{11:[1,2]}, {22:[3,4]}, {33:[5,6]], {34:[7]}]`, because it's better to have just `dict` object.

So program would look like this

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> listofdics = [{'StrId': 11, 'ProjId': 1},{'StrId': 11,'ProjId': 2},
              {'StrId': 22, 'ProjId': 3},{'StrId': 22, 'ProjId': 4},
              {'StrId': 33, 'ProjId': 5},{'StrId': 33, 'ProjId': 6},
              {'StrId': 34, 'ProjId': 7}]
>>> output = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in listofdics:
...     output[item.get('StrId')].append(item.get('ProjId'))
>>> dict(output)
{11: [1, 2], 22: [3, 4], 33: [5, 6], 34: [7]}
```

It's much easier to go through that dict that your desired output.

Comment: And you can always get that desired output this way: `[{k: v} for k, v in output.items()]`.